Is there a way to determinine partitions of $\mathbb{R}$ into two everywhere uncountable sets ? Can they be compatible with some arithmetic property?
Is there an explicit way of determining all partitions $ \{A,B\} $ of $\mathbb{R} $ such that for any open set $U$; $\ \lvert U \cap A \rvert = \lvert U \cap B \rvert \gt \lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert $ ? (that is, they both are everywhere uncountable)
If there was, would this contradict the property below ?
More precisely, is there a reasonable way to know if such a partition could have the following property for $x \neq y$:
$(x,y) \in (A \times A) \cup (B \times B) \iff \frac{x + y}{2} \in A$
This question is motivated by the problem in this post I made. 
One example of such a partition that doesn't respect the above property is to take A to be the set of reals with finitely many 1s in their base 3 extension. A is everywhere uncountable and it's complementary too

Please tell us what you think and show us what you've tried.

I am sure there is no explicit way to determine all the partitions of interest.  There are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ partitions of $\Bbb R$ and I would bet the everywhere uncountable does not reduce the cardinality.

@Ross Millikan: We can get $2^{\mathfrak c}$ many such partitions with the stronger property that "everywhere uncountable" is strengthened to "everywhere of full outer Lebesgue measure" (i.e. intersection with each open interval $(a,b)$ has outer Lebesgue measure equal to $b-a)$ by making use of the 1917 Luzin/Sierpiński result described in this mathoverflow answer -- the partitions arise by using the union of a subcollection of the $\mathfrak c$ many pairwise disjoint sets of full outer Lebesgue measure for one set and its complement for the other.

Easily fixed nit-pick: The sets there are subsets of $[0,1],$ but this is easily fixed by replacing each of those subsets of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue outer measure $1$ with the union of its countably many integer translations.

I don't understand your first question, but your "more precise" question has an easy negative answer, and it has nothing to do with uncountability. Suppose $\mathbb R=A\cup B$ where $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and
$$(x,y)\in(A\times A)\cup(B\times B)\implies\frac{x+y}2\in A.\tag1$$
Then $B=\varnothing$.
Proof. Assume for a contradiction that $B\ne\varnothing$. Constract an arithmetic progression of $19$ terms
$$x_{-9}\lt x_{-8}\lt\cdots\lt x_{-1}\lt x_0\lt x_1\lt\cdots\lt x_8\lt x_9$$
with $x_0\in B$.
Note that, for each $i\in\{1,\dots,9\}$, we have $x_i\in A\iff x_{-i}\in B$.
It is well known (and easily verified) that the Van der Waerden number $W(2,3)$ is equal to $9$. It follows that the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ contains a $3$-term arithmetic progression $i\lt j\lt k$ such that the numbers $x_i,x_j,x_k$ are either all in $B$ or else they are all in $A$. If they are all in $B$, then we have $x_i,x_k\in B$ and $\frac{x_i+x_k}2=x_j\in B$, contradicting $(1)$. If they are all in $A$, then we have $x_{-i},x_{-k}\in B$ and $\frac{x_{-i}+x_{-k}}2=x_{-j}\in B$, also contradicting $(1)$.

This is invariant under translation, so we can pick an element of $A$ and assume wlog it's $0$. Then for all $x$, $x$ and $-x$ are both in $A$ or both in $B$. Similarly, reflecting any point in $A$ in any other point in $A$ will make a third point in $A$.
If $a \in A$ then $\frac{a+0}{2} = \frac12 a \in A$. Now, let $a, b \in A$. Hence $\frac12 b , -a \in A$. By reflecting $-a$ in $\frac12 b$ we get $a+b \in A$ so we have that $A$ is a group.
$A$ isn't the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, so there is some coset of $A$ in $B$. But $A$ being closed under midpoints means its coset is closed under midpoints, so we can find $x, y \in B$ such that $\frac{x+y}{2} \in B$, which is a contradiction.
The only property of $A$ and $B$ this assumes in nonemptiness. Hence there is no partition of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying your property except $A = \mathbb{R}$.
